# Delete tags and entities from html file using C programming

Tags: c, file, file-io

I need to delete tags and entities from html file using C programming.

For example, if index.html is:

```
<div id="tekst"><h2>Naslov&nbsp; nastavak</h2><p>Ovo je <b>primjer</b> i <i>tekst</i> zadatka &copy; iz <a href="lekcija9">lekcije 9</a></p></div>
```

After deletion, it will be:

```
Naslov nastavakOvo je primjer i tekst zadatka  iz lekcije 9
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  const char index[] = "index.html";
  FILE *ulaz = fopen(index, "a+");
  char ch = fgetc(ulaz);
  int cc = ch;
  if (ulaz == NULL) {
    printf("Index.html doesn't exist.");
    return 1;
  }
  while (ch != EOF) {

    if (cc >= 65 && cc <= 90 || cc >= 97 && cc <= 122) {
      cc = ch;
      fputc(ch, ulaz);
    }
    ch = fgetc(ulaz);
    cc = ch;
  }
  fclose(ulaz);
 
  return 0;
}
```

I want to add character which is not tag or entity one by one to the beginning of html file. I would achieve that by setting cursor to the start of file, and after selection is over, program should delete everything what comes after the cursor.
Is this approach correct? If it is, could you help me implement it, or give me other better solution?

I have implemented this approach in my code, but I don't know where I made a mistake.

- Note: auxiliary arrays, strings, and html files are not allowed.

Comment: How does the posted code relate to what you want to do?

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). You need to make a genuine effort and ask about one specific problem. Not just list the whole task and then "help me".

Comment: I have written my code, and I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a good description. Give more details. What is the expected result vs actual result? What debugging did you do and where/what did you find starts going wrong?

Comment: Processing HTML with anything else than an HTML processing library is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: `char ch = fgetc(ulaz);` `fgetc` returns an `int` not a `char`. Need to make `int ch` otherwise can't store `EOF`.